# How to narrow down statuses to specific Campaign

Tags: visualforce, campaign, inputfield

I'm  building a custom VF page with a form to input data about interactions with campaign members.

I have this element on the form:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!campaign_member.status}"/>
```

Everything works out great, except the picklist which is rendered contains all of the possible statuses to have ever been created on this organization's account.  I would like it to show only this specific campaign's possible statuses.

How would you go about solving this?

Thanks in advance,

Rotem Tamir

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm                                               you will use selectoption now in apex controller code for this to work

Comment: I had considered that  - but - I can't find a way to query which member status values are availible per campaignId.  Any clue?

Comment: http://www.tgerm.com/2012/01/recordtype-specific-picklist-values.html                                                          have you seen this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Dunc44 for the feedback, final solution is as follows:

**Apex Controller:**

```
    public List<SelectOption> getMyOptions() {
     List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
     for (CampaignMemberStatus tmp : [select label from CampaignMemberStatus where campaignId=:campaign_member.campaignId]) {
             String lbl = (String)tmp.label;
             options.add(new SelectOption(lbl,lbl));
     }       

     return options;            
}
```

**VForce Page**

```
    <apex:selectList value="{!myStatus}" size="1" id="selStatus">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!myoptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't think of a way to do this with a standard inputfield, you can accomplish this with an `<apex:selectList> field.`  As for finding out which status goes with which campaign dynamically, I don't know if there is an easy way to accomplish this.

VF

```
<apex:selectList value="{!myStatus}" size="1">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!StatusOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Now in your controller, you can add the specific statuses that you want for this particular campaign

Apex

```
public string myStatus {get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getStatusOptions() {

     List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
     options.add(new SelectOption('Your Status 1','Your Status 1'));
     options.add(new SelectOption('Your Status 2','Your Status 2')); 
     //So on and so forth
     return options;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to create the same as you did. But I'm quite new to visualforce and apex. So I hope you can help me. I managed to create a visualforce page so campaignmembers can adjust their status. I created this with help of this blog: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006twk

Now I would like it to show only this specific campaign's possible statuses.

This is my apex class

```
p

ublic class UpdateCampaignMemberClass{

    public final CampaignMember cm;

    private ApexPages.StandardController cmController;

    public UpdateCampaignMemberClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        cmController = controller;
        this.cm= (CampaignMember)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference UpdateAction() {
             try{
            update cm;
            }
            catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            }

        return new PageReference('http://my.force.com/TEST/?id=' + cm.id );
    }   public string getStatus(string Status){
            return 'Status';
   } 



 }
```

And this is my vf page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="CampaignMember" extensions="UpdateCampaignMemberClass" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("&");
for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
var pair = vars[i].split("=");
if (pair[0] == variable) {
return pair[1];
}
} } 

function showAlert(variable){
    alert(variable);
    }
</script>


<apex:form >
    <b>Campaign Member ID </b><apex:inputfield value="{!campaignmember.Id}"/><br/><br/>
            Status <apex:inputfield value="{!campaignmember.status}"/><br/><br/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!UpdateAction}" />
     return new PageReference('www.google.com');

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks!
juul

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange, currently you've posted as an anwer, which is interpreted as a solution to the question posted. You'll be helped much better if you post your problem as a new Question, possibly with a reference to this question.