# how to narrow down statuses to a specific campaign

Tags: visualforce, campaign

Hi I created a visualforce page so contacts are able to update their campaignmemberstatus. I used this site: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006twk

The problem is that all statusses are visible. Now I would like it to show only the specific campaignid's possible statuses.

On this forum someone already found a solution, but I don't know how to adjust this in the apex class and vf page; [How to narrow down statuses to specific Campaign](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14785/)`how-to-narrow-down-statuses-to-specific-campaign`/15898#15898

Can someone please help me?

This is my apex class

```
public class UpdateCampaignMemberClass{

    public final CampaignMember cm;

    private ApexPages.StandardController cmController;

    public UpdateCampaignMemberClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        cmController = controller;
        this.cm= (CampaignMember)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference UpdateAction() {
             try{
            update cm;
            }
            catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            }

        return new PageReference('http://my.force.com/TEST/?id=' + cm.id );
    }   public string getStatus(string Status){
            return 'Status';
   } 



 }
```

And this is my vf page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="CampaignMember" extensions="UpdateCampaignMemberClass" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("&");
for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
var pair = vars[i].split("=");
if (pair[0] == variable) {
return pair[1];
}
} } 

function showAlert(variable){
    alert(variable);
    }
</script>


<apex:form >
    <b>Campaign Member ID </b><apex:inputfield value="{!campaignmember.Id}"/><br/><br/>
            Status <apex:inputfield value="{!campaignmember.status}"/><br/><br/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!UpdateAction}" />
     return new PageReference('www.google.com');

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks!
juul

Answer (score 1):

```
/*******************************************************************************************************
* @description Gives member statuses for a campaign 
* @param cid Id of the campaign to look up
* @return List of status names 
*/ 
public static list<string> getCampaignMemberStatuses(id cid) {
    list<string> memberStatuses = new list<string>();

    for (campaignMemberStatus cm : [select Label from CampaignMemberStatus 
        where campaignId =: cid order by SortOrder]) { 

        memberStatuses.add(cm.Label);
    }

    return (memberStatuses.isEmpty() ? null : memberStatuses);
}
```

Comment: Do we not need to instantiate the campaignmemberstatus reference? Do we not need to make it an object?